# Can I combine multiple property in visibility binding with MvvmCross?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have two `Boolean` properties in my ViewModel. Can I use combination of both properties to set visibility?

Something like

```
local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(BoolProperty1 && BoolProperty2)"
```

Comment: Yes you can, use a custom converter or combine both properties into one in your view model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one of the `ValueCombiner`s MvvmCross provides:

```
local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(And(BoolProperty1, BoolProperty2))"
```

You can read more about value combiners in the MvvmCross documentation: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-combiners

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using following way.

```
local:MvxBind="Visible And(BoolProperty1, BoolProperty2)"
```

Or You can use it with multiple condition like this.

```
local:MvxBind="Visible And(BoolProperty1, Or(BoolProperty2, BoolProperty3))"
```